# Python - Indentation error while using IDLE and if - else block, works fine on command line

Tags: python

I get the following indentation error

```
>>> number = 35
>>> if number == 35:
        print 'true'
    else:

  File "<pyshell#130>", line 3
    else:

^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>
```

This happens only on IDLE and not on command line. I am using Python 2.6.4 on Windows XP.
I have searched online, but not been able to find any answer as to why I get this error. Thankful for any help.

And to add - The code may not look properly indented when copied and pasted. But it was properly indented on the IDLE interface.

Comment: check if you are mixing tabs and spaces..

Comment: It's clearly a bug in IDLE in Windows, OP - I have a file that has no dedents, no tabs, all indents EXACTLY right (4 spaces), and I get this error sporadically. File runs precisely as expected on Wing and on the command line: similarly , IDLE often screws up  File->Open and arbitrarily replicates parts of the file. Don't use IDLE, is my basic point: it's the Windows 8 of quasi-IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> number = 35
>>> if number == 35:
...     print 'true'
... else:
...     print 'false'
... 
true
>>>
```

indent your code properly and manually

Answer (score 1):

Any block of code (started just after `:`) should have indent at least one space (or tab) more, than the parent one. In your example:

```
if number == 35:
    print 'true'
else:
    ...
```

But not:

```
if number == 35:
print 'true'
else:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not the way you wanted but it is clearly simple and effective:

**Instead of this:**

```
>>> number = 35
>>> if number == 35:
    print 'true'
else:
```

You can always check conditions on python idle **without using `if`** keyword such as:

```
>>> number = 35
>>> number == 35
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define indent manually

```
>>> number = 35
>>> if number == 35:
...     print 'true'
... else:
...     pass
... 
true
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
>>> if number == 35:
....print 'true'
else:
....print 'false'
```

true

Looks like the '>>> ' is not counted in indentation. I am using 2.7.13

Answer (score 0):

Correct, don't indent the else statement. I am using version 3.9

```py
if number == 35:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but the answer of Jan 13 else does look indented, based on how my version of IDLE3 looks with version 3.9.7. I was having all sorts of problems until I came here and finally got put on the right track. Manual indenting/non-indenting while letting IDLE3 drop indent otherwise is the key for me anyway. This is how I did things:

[image]